# Visibility of elements over different shades of blue

Tags: website-design, color

[image]

I'm debating which colors to use for my website. We've been trying to find the right colors for the logo and graphics of the site, and struggling with trying to pick between the light and dark blue.

What would be the advantages to one or the other?

Comment: Hi Omerta. I edited your question a little so it's not too specific and it can (potentially) help other people. Feel free to reedit and change / add any information you consider relevant :)

Comment: What color, if any, are the icons sitting on? That would play a LARGE part in which set will work better. In general terms, the pencil is too dark on the dark icon. As is the rocket.

Comment: It also depends on what color and tone of your background would be. Other than that i agree with all that yisela said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say in this case it all comes down to *contrast* and *consistency*.

Because you have light **and** dark elements in your icons, some of them get a little lost on top of the dark blue (the pencil, the board frames).

Also, some of your details (like the overlapping opaque shapes) are easier to appreciate in the lighter version. But most importantly for me, the use of a secondary color (pink) is more obvious in the second case. This creates a sort of **continuity** or identity that looks quite consistent.

Comment: as far as using colors to attract the average person, which do you think would be more effective? Also, do you think the logo looks better dark or light blue?

Comment: @Omerta I personally really like the light version, but it really depends (on many things, like what kind of company it is, for starts). I don't think it has to do with "effective", this is a very relative term. Light blue feels prettier and easier to see, but if the site is for a night club, then dark would be a better option. Very relative.